# jQuery .on not working with link after class is changed

Tags: jquery

In my code below, I change the `class` of a `link` from `user` to `red`. The idea is that a link with class red should not work on click. But it still does. Why does this happen? I was about to use `live`, but read it's deprecated and I should be using `on`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQuery.js"></script>

<script type="text/css">
.red{
color:red;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".user").on("click",function() {
    alert('Was Clicked');
        var idPri = $(this).data("id");
        var idSec = $(this).data("sec");
        $('.user[data-id="'+idPri+'"][data-sec="'+idSec+'"]').removeClass('user').addClass('red');
        $('.h2[data-id="'+idSec+'"]').find('span[data-sec="'+idSec+'"].user').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div class="h2" data-id="2">Who is your favorite Math teacher?
        <div>* User Name <span class="user" data-id="3" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
        <div>* User Name <span class="user" data-id="4" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
        <div>* User Name <span class="user" data-id="5" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
        <div>* User Name <span class="user" data-id="6" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
        <div>* User Name <span class="user" data-id="7" data-sec="2">Like</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using delegated events.But If you want to use `.user` class itself, then you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".user").on("click",function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('red')){
        return false;
    }
alert('Was Clicked');
    var idPri = $(this).data("id");
    var idSec = $(this).data("sec");

    $('.user[data-id="'+idPri+'"][data-sec="'+idSec+'"]').removeClass('user').addClass('red');
    $('.h2[data-id="'+idSec+'"]').find('span[data-sec="'+idSec+'"].user').remove();
    });

  });
```

check the demo here:http://jsfiddle.net/PkBAq/

Answer (score 3):

You're using direct event handlers. When you call `$(".user").on("click",function() {`, the event handlers are attached to your elements. Later when you change your class to `red`, ***the event handlers are already attached*** and will still fire. In your case, you could try delegated event handlers:

```
$("#container").on("click",".user",function() {
```

Delegated event handlers, on the other hand, are evaluated dynamically because the event handlers ***are not attached directly to the elements***, but to the container instead.

Comment: I tried using `live` and it works fine with the code I posted. Anything wrong using `live`?

Comment: @jmenezes: no, `#container` is the parent node that contains your `.user` elements.

Comment: @jmenezes: you should notice the second parameter `.on("click",".user"`. The second parameter is the selector that you need to delegate the event to the parent (`#container`)

Comment: @jmenezes: `.live` is not wrong and works in your case, but it's deprecated. In newer version of jQuery, it's recommended to use `.on`

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the `on` on the container so that events can be delegated.

```
$("#container").on("click",'.user',function() {
alert('Was Clicked');
    var idPri = $(this).data("id");
    var idSec = $(this).data("sec");
    $('.user[data-id="'+idPri+'"][data-sec="'+idSec+'"]').removeClass('user').addClass('red');
    $('.h2[data-id="'+idSec+'"]').find('span[data-sec="'+idSec+'"].user').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JPGqq/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".user","#container").on("click",function() {});
```